# How to push multiple items to an array based on checked value from multiple checkbox list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to populate an array based on selected/checked values from checkbox.
Let's say we have 3 arrays of strings

```
const cars = ["Ford", "Chevy", "Honda", "Toyota"];
const phones = ["iPhone", "Samsung", "Nokia", "Sony"];
const laptops = ["Mac", "Dell", "HP", "Acer"];
```

and another array which includes the checkbox values.

```
const names = ["cars", "phones", "laptops"];
```

My goal is to push to an array(let's say `selectedProductArray`) the array which has the same name as the checked value.
Here is what I did so far, which adds only one selected/checked array.

```
const selectedProductArray = [];
  const selectedProductInfo = nameArr.includes("phones")
    ? selectedProductArray.concat(phones)
    : nameArr.includes("laptops")
    ? selectedProductArray.concat(laptops)
    : selectedProductArray.concat(cars);
```

I am trying to push to the array multiple arrays based on checkbox selection.
For example, if there are checked `cars` and `phones` values in checkbox list, the desired array would look like so

```
["Ford", "Chevy", "Honda", "Toyota", "iPhone", "Samsung", "Nokia", "Sony];
```

The whole code and [demo sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/multipleselectcheckmarks-material-demo-forked-e44v2v?file=/demo.tsx:1112-1361)

```
import * as React from "react";
import OutlinedInput from "@mui/material/OutlinedInput";
import InputLabel from "@mui/material/InputLabel";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import ListItemText from "@mui/material/ListItemText";
import Select, { SelectChangeEvent } from "@mui/material/Select";
import Checkbox from "@mui/material/Checkbox";

const ITEM_HEIGHT = 48;
const ITEM_PADDING_TOP = 8;
const MenuProps = {
  PaperProps: {
    style: {
      maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 4.5 + ITEM_PADDING_TOP,
      width: 250
    }
  }
};

const cars = ["Ford", "Chevy", "Honda", "Toyota"];
const phones = ["iPhone", "Samsung", "Nokia", "Sony"];
const laptops = ["Mac", "Dell", "HP", "Acer"];

const names = ["cars", "phones", "laptops"];

export default function MultipleSelectCheckmarks() {
  const [nameArr, setNameArr] = React.useState<string[]>([]);

  const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent<typeof nameArr>) => {
    const {
      target: { value }
    } = event;
    setNameArr(typeof value === "string" ? value.split(",") : value);
  };

  const selectedProductArray = [];
  const selectedProductInfo = nameArr.includes("phones")
    ? selectedProductArray.concat(phones)
    : nameArr.includes("laptops")
    ? selectedProductArray.concat(laptops)
    : selectedProductArray.concat(cars);
  console.log("selectedProductInfo", selectedProductInfo);
  console.log("selectedProductArray", selectedProductArray);

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: 300 }}>
        <InputLabel id="demo-multiple-checkbox-label">Tag</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-multiple-checkbox-label"
          id="demo-multiple-checkbox"
          multiple
          value={nameArr}
          onChange={handleChange}
          input={<OutlinedInput label="Tag" />}
          renderValue={(selected) => selected.join(", ")}
          MenuProps={MenuProps}
        >
          {names.map((name) => (
            <MenuItem key={name} value={name}>
              <Checkbox checked={nameArr.indexOf(name) > -1} />
              <ListItemText primary={name} />
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Highly **not-recommended** and advised-against way: `nameArr.flatMap(x => eval(x))`. A better, sane/wise approach would be to reconsider the three arrays `cars`, `phones`, `laptops` & may be put those as key-value pairs in a common object (like: `const obj = { cars: ["Audi", "Porsche", ...], phones: ["ROG", "Pixel", ....], ...};`). Then, obj.cars will get the cars array. And, `nameArr.flatMap(x => obj[x]);`

Comment: Hey @jsN00b, thanks for the recommendation. I'll try  it.

Comment: Please try the approach using the `obj` object. Please **do NOT** try the `eval` one - it is a big **no-no**. :-)

Comment: @jsN00b thanks again for the answer. I tried the way you recommended. And here is what I got to. 
Could you, tell me, please, what  I am doing wrong https://codesandbox.io/s/multipleselectcheckmarks-material-demo-forked-r71zj7?file=/demo.tsx:599-757

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer aims to assist the OP to the below-stated objective,

> For example, if there are checked `cars` and `phones` values in checkbox
> list, the desired array would look like so

```
["Ford", "Chevy", "Honda", "Toyota", "iPhone", "Samsung", "Nokia", "Sony];
```

To do so, please make the below changes:

First, declare an object like this:

```
  const nameArrayOfObj = {
      cars: ["Ford", "Chevy", "Honda", "Toyota"],
      phones: ["iPhone", "Samsung", "Nokia", "Sony"],
      laptops: ["Mac", "Dell", "HP", "Acer"]
  };
```

Next, add the below line just under the outer/top-most `<div>`:

```
{JSON.stringify(nameArr.flatMap(name => nameArrayOfObj[name]))} <br/><br/><br/>
```

Now, when user selects the checkboxes `cars`, `phones`, `laptops` the corresponding items from those arrays will be rendered just above the `Select` dropdown.

[image: Image from codesandbox demo]